# Is there a way to use ShareDB with AWS API Gateway WebSocket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, sharedb

I'm developing a collaborative text editor, and the great [ShareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb) library was the best option I can find, very simple to use and accessible!

But now I'm figuring out where and how can I host a scalable backend handling ShareDB.

In the beginning, I was thinking of [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/elasticbeanstalk/), but I have some trouble making the WebSockets working on it. And then I discover [AWS API Gateway Websocket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html), which seems to be very versatile and useful for what I am searching for.

I was wondering if some of you ever tried to make these two interesting technologies work together?

Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Comment: What issues are you having getting it installed?

Comment: I'm curious that why shareDB is the best option? I have the similar question. I want to find a solution that is a scalable backend framework for the collaborative graphics editors.